# Regex extracting sub string python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a sub string from an exact point till a special character ", this is the string:

```
element = '<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2AZHZA23OLYLF" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="aa battery plus" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_6_2" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv5"><span class="s-heavy"></span>ab<span class="s-heavy">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>'
```

the part i want to extract is the keyword from: data-keyword=" till: the next " symbol, so in this case: aa battery plus

but I just get as result a letter, ever when limiting the string on left and right with the \b delimiter and square brackets.

I tried to use the re.findall() method

```
import re
element = '<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2AZHZA23OLYLF" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="aa batteries plus" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_6_2" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv5"><span class="s-heavy"></span>ab<span class="s-heavy">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>'
z = re.search(r'[\bdata-keyword="\b,'""']',element).group(0)
print(z)
```

This is what I get:

```
d
Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I only extract the keyword? 
IE: aa batteries plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` function:

```
import re
element = '<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2AZHZA23OLYLF" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="aa battery plus" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_6_2" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv5"><span class="s-heavy"></span>ab<span class="s-heavy">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>'
output = re.findall(r'data-keyword="(.*?)"', element)[0]
print(output)
```

**Output**

> aa battery plus

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text between two strings, You'll need to use this regex format.

```
import re

element = '<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2AZHZA23OLYLF" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="aa batteries plus" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_6_2" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv5"><span class="s-heavy"></span>ab<span class="s-heavy">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>'

z = re.search(r'data-keyword="(.*?)"', element).group(1)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its is not a good idea to use Regex to parse HTML. Instead you can use a html parser like BeautifulSoup.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

element = '<div class="s-suggestion" data-alias="aps" data-crid="2AZHZA23OLYLF" data-isfb="false" data-issc="false" data-keyword="aa battery plus" data-nid="" data-reftag="nb_sb_ss_i_6_2" data-store="" data-type="a9" id="issDiv5"><span class="s-heavy"></span>ab<span class="s-heavy">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(element, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", class_="s-suggestion")["data-keyword"])
```

**Output:**

```
aa battery plus
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression might likely work here, even though it may not be the best idea, for which we might want to approach solving the problem using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613790/6553328), yet if we have to:

```
data-keyword="\s*([^"]+?)\s*"
```

might also remove the undesired spaces before and after our desired data.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/OkpPPg/1/)

#### TEST

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"data-keyword=\"\s*([^\"]+?)\s*\""

test_str = ("<div class=\"s-suggestion\" data-alias=\"aps\" data-crid=\"2AZHZA23OLYLF\" data-isfb=\"false\" data-issc=\"false\" data-keyword=\"aa batteries plus\" data-nid=\"\" data-reftag=\"nb_sb_ss_i_6_2\" data-store=\"\" data-type=\"a9\" id=\"issDiv5\"><span class=\"s-heavy\"></span>ab<span class=\"s-heavy\">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>\n"
    "<div class=\"s-suggestion\" data-alias=\"aps\" data-crid=\"2AZHZA23OLYLF\" data-isfb=\"false\" data-issc=\"false\" data-keyword=\"    aa batteries plus     \" data-nid=\"\" data-reftag=\"nb_sb_ss_i_6_2\" data-store=\"\" data-type=\"a9\" id=\"issDiv5\"><span class=\"s-heavy\"></span>ab<span class=\"s-heavy\">reva cold sore treatment</span></div>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
Match 1 was found at 105-137: data-keyword="aa batteries plus"
Group 1 found at 119-136: aa batteries plus
Match 2 was found at 417-458: data-keyword="    aa batteries plus     "
Group 1 found at 435-452: aa batteries plus
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex for this. 
You can simply search for the index of 'data-keyword' with the built-in function `find(substring,begin,end)`. Then perform a search for the index for each of the following parentheses and slice the text that is between these.

```
i_key = element.find('data-keyword')
i_1 = element.find('"', i_key)
i_2 = element.find('"', i_1+1)
z = element[i_1+1:i_2]
```

More info on the [find function](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/find.html).

Answer (score 1):

While I totally agree with the previous answer you can consider the next solution as well:

```
element.split('data-keyword="')[-1].split('" data-nid')[0]
```

This may be considered quite convenient when you need to parse "structured" inputs...